# Still requiring Login-RmAzureAccount even after importing PublishSettings in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I am attempting to login to an Azure account through a PowerShell script by means of making use of a publishsettings file; However, I am still finding that it is requiring me to login to my account using `Login-AzureRmAccount`, regardless of having those credentials.

My step-by step looks something like this:

Clear out all accounts that may be available:
`Get-AzureAccount | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureAccount $_.ID -Force }`

Download the PublishSettings file: `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile $PublishSettingsFileNameWithPath`

Select the Azure subscription using the subscription ID: 
`Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId`

And finally, create a new resource group in the subscription before deploying it: `New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force 2>> .\errorCIMS_RG.txt | Out-File .\rgDetailsCIMS_RG.txt`

However, *this* is when an error is thrown: `Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.`

Assuming I have the PublishSettings file, and it hasnt expired, why would this be giving back an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mihail said, we should **check Azure PowerShell version** first, and install the latest version.
We can run this command to list Azure PowerShell version:
`Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

By the way, `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` work for ASM, `New-AzureRmResourceGroup` is ARM command, so if you want to create resource group, you should `Login-AzureRmAccount` first.

**Note**:

> The AzureResourceManager module does **not** support publish settings
>   files.

More information about `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile`, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/import-azurepublishsettingsfile?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

Comment: Does it work now?  Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating to last version of azure powershell cmdlet.
You can find last one here:
    https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

Comment: I can't mark my answer :) probably other people can